# Should I check if an element hasClass() before I removeClass()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I definitely want to remove a certain class from an element, should I blindly call `removeClass()` or should I check with `hasClass()` first?

Is there any mentionable performance advantage in either of these methods? Is there a best practice for this?

Example:

```
function showMessage(){
    $('.message').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

vs.

```
function showMessage(){
    if($('.message').hasClass('hidden')){
        $('.message').removeClass('hidden');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say this comes down to personal preference but since `removeClass` doesn't care if the class exists or not, I'd just call it without checking

Comment: The second example would have overhead, not really at fault of `.hasClass`, but rather because you've repeated a DOM lookup. Better off storing your collections as variables where possible: `var $message = $(".message");`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call to [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) doesn't throw any errors if the class is not present on the element(s), so there really is no need to call [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) first. It just causes additional overhead.

When asking about performance though, the calls to `getClass()` and `removeClass()` are likely to be fast. It's the repeated lookup of the `.message` elements in the DOM that will slow things down. So, in case you want to call `hasClass()` first, it's better not to repeat the element lookup:

```
function showMessage() {
    const message = $('.message');

    if(message.hasClass('hidden')){
        message.removeClass('hidden');
    }
}
```

Comment: The DOM lookup overload is a great hint! Does this also go for usage of `$(this)` within `on()`? Should I store `$(this)` in a variable if I plan to use it several times?

Comment: Yup, probably a good idea. There is a cost involved in wrapping a DOM element into a JQuery object.

Comment: @user2015253 `$(this)` (or any direct jQuery wrapping of a DOM element) is reasonably fast / low cost. That being said, why not store the result anyway?